# When is $x$ a square in $\mathbb{F}_p[x]/(Q) $?

Tags: number-theory, finite-fields, quadratic-residues

Let $p$ be a prime and $Q$ be an irreducible polynomial over $\mathbb{F}_p[x]$. Which are all $p$ and $Q$ such that there exists a polynomial $R(x) \in \mathbb{F}_p[x]$ such that $Q$ divides $x - R^2$?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: @Mummytheturkey I think it's supposed to be the finite field, because of the tag "finite-fields".

Comment: The quotient $\mathbb{Z}_p[x]/(Q)$ is a field and so its multiplicative group must be cyclic. So we are looking for when $k$ is even in $g^k \equiv x \pmod Q$. But then no idea.

Comment: @Mummy Yeah sorry it's finite field, edited now..

Comment: Well, Euler’s criterion comes to mind for odd $p$: one way to characterize $Q$ is that it must be a degree $d$ irreducible factor of $x^(p^d-1)/2 - 1$.  When $p=2$ the question of squareness gets substantially easier.

Comment: Yeah sure, that follows easily from the primitive root. But can we be more precise?

Comment: @DesmondMiles Per wikipedia it seems there is an easy argument that these factors should all come from the cyclotomic polynomial $\Phi_{(p^d-1)/2}(x)$.  So I think you can probably express these explicitly in terms of primitive roots of unity in an algebraic extension of $\mathbb F_p$.

Comment: @DesmondMiles Oh right, there can also be contributions from smaller cyclotomic factors $\Phi_r$ for $r$ dividing $(p^d-1)/2$.  When the order of $p$ mod $r$ is exactly $d$ and not smaller.  So for prime $d$ I guess this happens fairly often.

Comment: For $Q$ irreducible then $x$ is a square in $\Bbb{F}_p[x]/(Q)$ iff $Q(x^2)$ is reducible

Answer (score -1):

Outsorcing https://planetmath.org/quadraticreciprocityforpolynomials
gives an immediate answer. One can look up on their own a proof of polynomial QR, but does anyone have an idea if there is a simpler proof for the particular case for when $x$ is a square? (Apart from blindly simplifying as much as possible the general QR proof.)